# How do I fix the stuck typing bug?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

When the map zone changes and I'm typing, I will get stuck inside that mode and unable to get out of it, even enter, escape, etc does not close the box.  The only way out is to restart the game, how do I fix this bug?

Comment: Did you try hitting the button that brings up the console (~ by default)?

Comment: @Shaun: No, that doesn't work.  As far as I'm aware, the only way to fix it is to close the game and restart.  We'll just have to wait for a patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [new patch](http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?4963-Current-%287.05c%29-and-Upcoming-%287.06%29-Patch-Notes) fixes this issue.

> - Fixed chatbox getting stuck during level transitions

Answer (score 2):

The 7.06 patch that came out recently has fixed this issue.